# make subway graph include 102 topics in ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

This is a followup from [subway-style graph for word frequency across three datasets in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993343/subway-style-graph-for-word-frequency-across-three-datasets-in-ggplot2)

I used the code in the answer from this question, **but am struggling with how best to manipulate the graph to make it fits 100 unique dict entries within the subway graph without completely messing up the dict word entries on the margins.**

I have tested out different amounts of words to feed into the subway graph, and found that it cannot contain more than 25 words.

I have data:

```
structure(list(dict = c("apple", "apple", "apple", 
"mandarin", "mandarin", "mandarin", "orange", "orange", "orange", "pear"), 
    name = c("freq_ongov", "freq_onindiv", "freq_onmedia", "freq_ongov", 
    "freq_onindiv", "freq_onmedia", "freq_ongov", "freq_onindiv", 
    "freq_onmedia", "freq_ongov"), value = c(0, 87, 63, 0, 44, 
    20, 3, 27, 25, 0), rank = c(26, 85, 70, 26, 61, 42.5, 86, 
    47, 48, 26)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    name = c("freq_ongov", "freq_onindiv", "freq_onmedia"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L), c(2L, 5L, 8L), c(3L, 6L, 9L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But there are 100 rows within this data that I want to include in the following code:

```
leftlabels <- df$dict[df$name == "freq_ongov"]
leftlabels <- leftlabels[order(df$rank[df$name == "freq_ongov"])]

rightlabels <- df$dict[df$name == "freq_onmedia"]
rightlabels <- rightlabels[order(df$rank[df$name == "freq_onmedia"])]

ggplot(df, aes(name, rank, color = dict, group = dict)) +
  geom_line(size = 4) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "white", size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(max(df$rank)), labels = leftlabels,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~., breaks = seq(max(df$rank)), 
                                         labels = rightlabels)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  guides(color = guide_none()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "points"))
```

I tried changing the `y.int` and width of the y axis to fit in 100 words, but that only makes the y-axis longer, without changing the spacing between each word label on the y-axis, so all the words get squeezed together. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Just the labels are squished? Have you tried making the plot device taller so there's more room? I'm not sure I see a programming question here. Seems like a design question. Perhaps you could clarify. Also I can't get your sample code to run. Is the data you supplied supposed to be `dictfreq`?

Comment: @MrFlick apologies - edited the OG post. the problem is that the coding for the graph right now only permits 25 words per graph, otherwise the words are completely squished on top of each other. i tried making the plot taller (y.axis) but that doesn't seem to change the space between the word labels when there are 100 words, which is what i need to do.

Comment: I still can't run this code. If data sample data is supposed to be `df` then there is no `dict` column. Perhaps you can just generate some fake data with enough works to replicate the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick dict is the same as words. i changed it in the og post, it should work now